# Splitting vector bundles on $\mathbb{P}^n$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, cohomology, vector-bundles

There are results by Kleiman and Sumihiro that claim you can split an algebraic vector bundles (in the sense that it admits filtration that quotients are given by line bundles) by applying respectively blow-ups and finite covers. I always wondered whether there can be any sort of splitting criterion in the sense you can split a short exact sequence of vector bundles into a direct sum using any of these techniques for let's say something very simple like a projective space. So the question is it possible to kill the first cohomology of vector-bundles by a combination of finite covers and blow-ups (along smooth subvarieties)?

Comment: Over $\mathbf{C}$, $H^i(X, \mathcal{O}_X)$ is a direct summand of $H^i(X, \mathbf{C})$. If $f\colon Y\to X$ is a surjective map of smooth projective varieties, then $f^*\colon H^i(X, \mathbf{C})\to H^i(Y, \mathbf{C})$ is injective (standard argument using Poincare duality and multisections), and hence so is $f^*\colon H^i(X, \mathcal{O}_X)\to H^i(Y, \mathcal{O}_Y)$. Bottom line: you cannot kill $H^i(X, \mathcal{O}_X)$ by surjective maps from smooth varieties.

Comment: If you are only interested in $X=\mathbf{P}^n$, try splitting the Euler sequence $$ 0\to \Omega^1_X \to \mathcal{O}_X(-1)^{n+1} \to \mathcal{O}_X\to 0.$$ Its class in ${\rm Ext}^1(\mathcal{O}_X, \Omega^1_X) = H^1(X, \Omega^1_X)$ is nonzero. Now by the same argument as above, for every surjective $f\colon Y\to X$ with $Y$ smooth and projective, $H^1(X, \Omega^1_X)\to H^1(Y, \Omega^1_Y)$ is injective, and hence so is $H^1(X, \Omega^1_X) \to H^1(Y, f^*\Omega^1_X)$. So the Euler sequence does not split after pull back to any such $Y$.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. So it seems to be impossible in char $0$. In char $p$ you can kill $H^1(X,\mathcal{O}_X)$ by Frobenius and etale covers. In our case etale fundamental groups are trivial so you can kill it by just Frobenius. But I don't know about the Euler sequence in char $p$...